# Screen Width Query working incorrectly with SCSS and Create React App

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, create-react-app

I am using SASS 5.0.0 with Create React App on an `.scss` file and the Navbar is always hidden.
The Screen Width Query is working incorrectly.
I am trying to make a different Navbar for Mobile. It is not fully made yet. Only the hiding of it.

`App.scss`:

```
@import "_var.scss";

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

body {
  font-size: 28px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: $mainWhite;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex
}

li {
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
li a {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;

  .nbd {
    visibility: visible;
  }

}
}
.nbd {
  visibility: hidden;
}
li a {
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: $mainWhite;
}

.active {
  background-color: $mainWhite;
}

.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: $mainBlack;
  margin: 6px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: $mainWhite;
}

.f {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding: 5px;
}
/*Images*/
.imgSize1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.imgSize2 {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}

.imgSize3 {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
/*Images*/

.grey {
  background-color: lighten($mainBlack, 15%);
}
```

`_var.scss`:

```
$mainWhite: #fff;
$mainBlack: #000;
```

Comment: What element(s) have class nbd?

Comment: <ul> has it. @AHaworth

Comment: But you are putting the .nbd setting in the media query on the li a .nbd

Comment: The mobile one will be smaller.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't making sense to me. Why are you putting li a .ndb to visible for wider devices if the ndb class is on a ul, not on a li a?

Comment: The nbd and nbm are for visibility. There are 2 ul elements. The mobile one is an icon list and the other one is text. So they can fit on both devices evenly.